# can't remove phpmyadmin in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I try to remove phpmyadmin and later re-install, but is not workin with this line sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin*

```
 sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
dbconfig-common dbconfig-no-thanks fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core javascript-common libfontconfig1 libgd3
libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libtiff5 libwebp6 libxpm4 libzip4
php-bz2 php-curl php-gd php-phpseclib php-tcpdf php-zip php7.2-bz2 php7.2-curl php7.2-gd php7.2-zip
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
phpmyadmin*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 25.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--remove):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!.  "...you should reinstall it before attempting a removal..."   Have you tried this?  If you have, please include the output of that, too.

Comment: Try as @tudor suggested `sudo apt install --reinstall phpmyadmin` and then remove it `sudo apt purge phpmyadmin` (without star at the end).